# Concurrent Programming issue java

Tags: java, concurrency

So I am down to figuring out how to get the objects to keep track of how many diamonds they take with each iteration of the executor service

```
public class DwarfMine {

    public DwarfMine() {
    }

    public int diamonds = 100;

    public int getDiamonds() {
        return diamonds;
    }

    public synchronized int subtractDiamonds(int howMany) {
        diamonds -= howMany;
        System.out.println("There are now " + diamonds + " left in the mine!");
        return diamonds;
    }

}
```

Comment: The method is synchronized, meaning that the _object_ is locked when calling the `run` method. Because each DwarfMiner has its own object, they can run simultaneously whether they are locked or not.

Comment: Putting `synchronized` on each `run` method isn't going to work as each instance of DwarfMine (`sneezy`, `dopey`) is going to have its own monitor (mutex) so there is no synchronization that is going to take place. Also, each instance of DwarfMine is going to have its own count of diamonds... is this what you want? Wouldn't there be one shared DwarfMine instance with several Dwarf instances visiting it? You may want to rethink how you are modeling things.

Comment: No,  My intent was to only have the one mine with the 7 dwarfs(threads) pulling from the one mine.  Thank you for the responses I kind of pick up what you are saying, but am new to working with threads

Comment: After reading your responses you are absolutely correct I have 7 dwarfs pulling from 7 mines.... How do I split that mine into a global variable such that each dwarf would pull from that one mine.

Comment: By heavily editing your original question the old comments s and answers are hard for others to follow. Next time, might be better to stick with one problem/question per posting here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each `DwarfMine` instance (`sneezy`, `dopey`) has its own lock/mutex/monitor so putting `synchronized` on the `run` method doesn't synchronize anything as each method is working with a different "lock".

I think it would be easier to understand if you had separate classes for `Mine` and `Dwarf`. If you had an `extractDiamonds` method on the `Mine` you could put `synchronized` on that method and achieve what you want. This is assuming you would create a single `Mine` object instance and somehow pass it to each `Dwarf` instance you create... or something similar.

Comment: I am trying this as we speak, not sure how it will work.  I will post results if I get it working with this

Comment: I still have not solved this, however I feel I am getting closer.  Will be updating post with current code. Thank you again